# Count non-default template arguments with metaprogramming?

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, c++03

I have a template class that accepts from 1 to 8 integer arguments. The permitted range for each argument is 0..15. A default value of 16 for each argument allows me to detect unused arguments.

I would like to have the number of user-supplied arguments available as a compile-time constant. I can do this using a template helper class and a lot of partial specialisation.

My question is, can I clean this up using a bit of recursive metaprogramming. What I have works but it feels like it could be improved syntactically.

Variadic templates and anything else c++0x are not available to me, sadly.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <iostream>

template<uint8_t p0,uint8_t p1,uint8_t p2,uint8_t p3,uint8_t p4,uint8_t p5,uint8_t p6,uint8_t p7>
struct Counter { enum { COUNT=8 }; };

template<uint8_t p0,uint8_t p1,uint8_t p2,uint8_t p3,uint8_t p4,uint8_t p5,uint8_t p6>
struct Counter<p0,p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6,16> { enum { COUNT=7 }; };

template<uint8_t p0,uint8_t p1,uint8_t p2,uint8_t p3,uint8_t p4,uint8_t p5>
struct Counter<p0,p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,16,16> { enum { COUNT=6 }; };

template<uint8_t p0,uint8_t p1,uint8_t p2,uint8_t p3,uint8_t p4>
struct Counter<p0,p1,p2,p3,p4,16,16,16> { enum { COUNT=5 }; };

template<uint8_t p0,uint8_t p1,uint8_t p2,uint8_t p3>
struct Counter<p0,p1,p2,p3,16,16,16,16> { enum { COUNT=4 }; };

template<uint8_t p0,uint8_t p1,uint8_t p2>
struct Counter<p0,p1,p2,16,16,16,16,16> { enum { COUNT=3 }; };

template<uint8_t p0,uint8_t p1>
struct Counter<p0,p1,16,16,16,16,16,16> { enum { COUNT=2 }; };

template<uint8_t p0>
struct Counter<p0,16,16,16,16,16,16,16> { enum { COUNT=1 }; };


template<uint8_t p0,uint8_t p1=16,uint8_t p2=16,uint8_t p3=16,
         uint8_t p4=16,uint8_t p5=16,uint8_t p6=16,uint8_t p7=16>
struct MyClass {

  void printArgCount() {
    std::cout << Counter<p0,p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6,p7>::COUNT << std::endl;
  }
};


main() {
  MyClass<4,7,8,12,15,1> foo;

  foo.printArgCount();
}
```

Comment: Looks good to me. I doubt there’s a better solution.

Comment: I don't suppose Boost's variadic templates are an option to get as many arguments as the user wants to pass?

Comment: I noted a difference of behavior between mine and Crog's solution: his count all non-16 parameters, I count up to the first parameter that is 16. At the moment, I think we may both be wrong and we should in fact count up to the latest paramater that is not 16... does it matter to you ?

Comment: What's wrong with `(p1 != 16) + (p2 != 16) +...` ?

Comment: @Matthieu: no it doesn't matter, they both work for me. It is not legal for the user to supply a 16 anywhere in the list so either counting up to the first 16 or all non-16 will work just fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not just checking the first `16` that appears ?

```
template <uint8_t p0, ...>
struct Counter {
    enum { COUNT = (p1 == 16 ? 1 : 
                    p2 == 16 ? 2 :
                    p3 == 16 ? 3 :
                    p4 == 16 ? 4 :
                    p5 == 16 ? 5 :
                    p6 == 16 ? 6 :
                    p7 == 16 ? 7 :
                               8
                   ) };
};
```

Comment: Very neat indeed. I had no idea you could do this kind of logic in an enum declaration.

Comment: @AndyBrown: You can use most (all ?) built-in functions for constant expressions (`enum`, `static <built-in> const` inline definitions, template non-type parameters, ...). For example `sizeof` is game too.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this but its still not as pretty/nice as some other solutions others may give using c++11:

```
template< uint8_t p0 = 16,uint8_t p1 = 16,uint8_t p2 = 16,uint8_t p3 = 16,uint8_t p4 = 16,uint8_t p5 = 16,uint8_t p6 = 16,uint8_t p7 = 16>
struct Counter 
{ 
    enum { COUNT= int(p0!=16) + int(p1!=16) + int(p2!=16) + int(p3!=16) + int(p4!=16) + int(p5!=16) + int(p6!=16) + int(p7!=16) }; 

    int count() const
    { return  COUNT; }
};
```

Comment: Aren't default template arguments part of C++11?

Comment: No, default template arguments for classes have been there for a long time to my knowledge as I have always used them. Somebody may know exactly when they appeared maybe

Comment: @chris: default arguments on *functions* are part of C++11.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the counter recursively, something like this:

```
template<typename>
struct Counter;

template<>
struct Counter<> { static const int COUNT = 0;};

template<typename T, typename... Args>
struct count<T, Args...> //partial specialization
{ static const int value = 1 + count<Args...>::COUNT;};
```

Comment: You might have missed the change, but no C++11.